# How to consult FAT32 cluster size on Ubuntu

Tags: format, sd-card, fat32

I have to format an SD Card to FAT32 using 64 KB cluster size specifically.

This is possible using `mkdosfs`, using command `-s 128`.
It seems to work as intended, it follows all online helps which are consistent with documentation, and the produced partition is usable.

But nowhere can I "read" the *cluster size* information once the partition is formatted, which makes me wonder how I can check if the cluster size is the intended one. `disks` doesn't provide this information. `fdisk -l` doesn't provide this information. `gparted` doesn't provide this information.

Is there a way to consult the cluster size of a formatted FAT32 partition on Linux ?
Is there any additional concern if the formatted partition is on an SD card ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the `ll` command and the [size of directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234065/why-size-reporting-for-directories-is-different-than-other-files) will be your block size (cluster size in Windows speak):

```
$ ll /
total 40972
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root     4096 Apr  8 16:30 ./
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root     4096 Apr  8 16:30 ../
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Mar 31 16:44 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root     4096 Apr  8 16:32 boot/
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root     4096 Aug  2  2018 cdrom/
```

My block size is 4,096 (4K) which is normal for an `ext4` Linux file system. In your case it will be 64K and even a file of 1 byte will take 64K bytes on disk.

Comment: Yep, that works, I can see that all directory entries are 64 KB, and I guess it infers that the cluster size must be 64 KB.

Answer (score 5):

I found another solution, `dosfsck`.

More specifically, add `-v` to see FS details, and `-n` to ensure it doesn't do anything else, and it gives a pretty complete description :

```
> sudo dosfsck -v -n /dev/sde1

fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Checking we can access the last sector of the filesystem
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
 Automatically removing dirty bit.
Boot sector contents:
System ID "mkfs.fat"
Media byte 0xf8 (hard disk)
       512 bytes per logical sector
     65536 bytes per cluster
       128 reserved sectors
First FAT starts at byte 65536 (sector 128)
         2 FATs, 32 bit entries
  15663104 bytes per FAT (= 30592 sectors)
Root directory start at cluster 2 (arbitrary size)
Data area starts at byte 31391744 (sector 61312)
```

Comment: +1 as I never knew `dosfsck` even existed in my Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: For whatever reason, this doesn't work with a FA32-formatted SD card here.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```bsh
file -s /dev/partition
```

Or:

```bsh
minfo -i /dev/partition
```

*Source: [FAT –  Detecting FAT Type | ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/FAT#Detecting_FAT_type)*

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one way to find the cluster size of a FAT file system:

- Use the `fsck.fat` command from the `dosfstools` package
- Use the `minfo` command from the `mtools` package

Both `dosfstools` and `mtools` are FAT-specific utilities. Since `dosfstools` is installed by default on Ubuntu (and many other distributions, I bet), it is recommended. In fact, `mkdosfs` (a.k.a. `mkfs.fat`) is also from the same package. As you can see in the examples below, `dosfstools` feels much cleaner, while `mtools` provides more low-level information.

---

### Example with fsck.fat

Please note that `dosfsck` (as mentioned in [Cyan's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233195/620399)) is a symbolic link to `fsck.fat`. In fact, there are only 3 executables in the `dosfstools` package. Other names are just symlinks:

```
                      dosfslabel → fatlabel
dosfsck / fsck.msdos / fsck.vfat → fsck.fat
mkdosfs / mkfs.msdos / mkfs.vfat → mkfs.fat
```

Execute the following command:

```sh
sudo fsck.fat -n -v /dev/sdb1
```

#### macOS-Formatted USB Pen Drive

The device is a USB pen drive initialized with Disk Utility on macOS. The file system is new (just formatted) and clean (properly unmounted). The result looks like this:

```
fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
Checking we can access the last sector of the filesystem
Boot sector contents:
System ID "BSD  4.4"
Media byte 0xf0 (5.25" or 3.5" HD floppy)
       512 bytes per logical sector
       512 bytes per cluster
        32 reserved sectors
First FAT starts at byte 16384 (sector 32)
         2 FATs, 32 bit entries
   1613312 bytes per FAT (= 3151 sectors)
Root directory start at cluster 2 (arbitrary size)
Data area starts at byte 3243008 (sector 6334)
    403266 data clusters (206472192 bytes)
32 sectors/track, 16 heads
         0 hidden sectors
    409600 sectors total
Checking for unused clusters.
Checking free cluster summary.
/dev/sdb1: 1 files, 1/403266 clusters
```

This line tells you the cluster size is 512 bytes:

```
       512 bytes per cluster
```

#### Linux-Formatted USB Pen Drive

Here is the result for the same USB pen drive, partitioned and formatted on Ubuntu Linux:

```
fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
Checking we can access the last sector of the filesystem
Boot sector contents:
System ID "mkfs.fat"
Media byte 0xf8 (hard disk)
       512 bytes per logical sector
      4096 bytes per cluster
        32 reserved sectors
First FAT starts at byte 16384 (sector 32)
         2 FATs, 32 bit entries
    524288 bytes per FAT (= 1024 sectors)
Root directory start at cluster 2 (arbitrary size)
Data area starts at byte 1064960 (sector 2080)
    130811 data clusters (535801856 bytes)
63 sectors/track, 255 heads
      2048 hidden sectors
   1048572 sectors total
Checking for unused clusters.
Checking free cluster summary.
/dev/sdb1: 0 files, 1/130811 clusters
```

This line tells you the cluster size is 4096 bytes:

```
      4096 bytes per cluster
```

---

### Example with minfo

Execute the following command:

```sh
sudo minfo -i /dev/sdb1
```

#### macOS-Formatted USB Pen Drive

The device is a USB pen drive initialized with Disk Utility on macOS. The file system is new (just formatted) and clean (properly unmounted). The result looks like this:

```
Hidden (40) does not match sectors (32)
device information:
===================
filename="/dev/sdb1"
sectors per track: 32
heads: 16
cylinders: 800

media byte: f0

mformat command line:
  mformat -t 800 -h 16 -s 32 -r 0 -c 1 -i "/dev/sdb1" ::

bootsector information
======================
banner:"BSD  4.4"
sector size: 512 bytes
cluster size: 1 sectors
reserved (boot) sectors: 32
fats: 2
max available root directory slots: 0
small size: 0 sectors
media descriptor byte: 0xf0
sectors per fat: 0
sectors per track: 32
heads: 16
hidden sectors: 0
big size: 409600 sectors
physical drive id: 0x0
reserved=0x0
dos4=0x29
serial number: 67E317ED
disk label="EFI        "
disk type="FAT32   "
Big fatlen=3151
Extended flags=0x0000
FS version=0x0000
rootCluster=2
infoSector location=1
backup boot sector=6

Infosector:
signature=0x41615252
free clusters=403265
last allocated cluster=3
```

These lines tell you the cluster size is 512 bytes:

```
sector size: 512 bytes
cluster size: 1 sectors
```

#### Linux-Formatted USB Pen Drive

Here is the result for the same USB pen drive, partitioned and formatted on Ubuntu Linux:

```
Hidden (2048) does not match sectors (63)
device information:
===================
filename="/dev/sdb1"
sectors per track: 63
heads: 255
cylinders: 66

media byte: f8

mformat command line:
  mformat -T 1048572 -h 255 -s 63 -H 0 -r 0 -c 8 -L 1024 -i "/dev/sdb1" ::

bootsector information
======================
banner:"mkfs.fat"
sector size: 512 bytes
cluster size: 8 sectors
reserved (boot) sectors: 32
fats: 2
max available root directory slots: 0
small size: 0 sectors
media descriptor byte: 0xf8
sectors per fat: 0
sectors per track: 63
heads: 255
hidden sectors: 2048
big size: 1048572 sectors
physical drive id: 0x80
reserved=0x0
dos4=0x29
serial number: 8B7B3859
disk label="EFI        "
disk type="FAT32   "
Big fatlen=1024
Extended flags=0x0000
FS version=0x0000
rootCluster=2
infoSector location=1
backup boot sector=6

Infosector:
signature=0x41615252
free clusters=130810
last allocated cluster=2
```

These lines tell you the cluster size is 4096 bytes:

```
sector size: 512 bytes
cluster size: 8 sectors
```